# how to return instead of break in java

Tags: java, boolean, return, break

I am writing an algorithm that returns true if three elements from a list a are able to sum up to three. Each element in a list can be repeated, so whenever there is a 0, I will have true. My question is not on the algorithm, albeit I do need a revision (an extra constraint) on the second if statement for this algorithm to be complete. After reading the responses, I have revised my code to just return. Now there is an output of nothing from my code, but I believe it is because I need to adjust my second condition.

```
public class main {

public static void main(String args[]) {
int[] a = { -6, 2, 4 }; // true -6, 2, 4
// int [] a = {-6, 2, 5};  false
// int [] a = {-6, 3, 10, 200}; true -6, 3, 3
// int [] a = {8, 2, -1, 15}; true  2, -1, -1
// int [] a = {8, 2, -1, -1, 15}; true 2, -1, -1
// int [] a = {5, 1, 0, 3, 6}; true 0, 0, 0
sum(a);
}

public static boolean sum(int[] a) {
int x = 0;
int len = a.length;
boolean check = false;
while (x < len) {
    if (a[x] == 0) {

        check = true;

        if (check == true)
        {System.out.println("break time yo@");
        break;}
    }
    if (a[x] + a[x + 1] + a[x + 2] == 0 ) {
        check = true;
        if (check == true)
            {break;}
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= len; i++) {
        if ((i == 2 * a[x]) || (2 * i == a[x])) {
            check = true;
            if (check == true)
                {break;}
        }
    }
    x += 1;
}

return check;
}

}
```

Comment: Why would there be one more `true`?  Your code only has `System.out.println(check);` once.  Why are you expecting it to happen twice?

Comment: @DavidWallace I thought one true would be from System.out.println(check) and the second would be from return check (the line after System.out.println(check). I am just starting to learn java on my own. Previously I have been using python, so maybe there is something obvious I am not understanding.

Comment: But `return check;` doesn't mean "print this".  It just means "stop running this method, and return the value to whatever method called it".  There's no automatic printing of returned values.

Comment: It looks like you will have array index out of bounds exception if your while loop make one more iteration then single iteration. You are adding x+1, x+2...

Comment: @NenadBulatovic Right, I mentioned that in my post. I will work on that now. However, why my code now outputs nothing still leaves me confused.

Comment: Please DON'T change your question after people start answering it.  It makes all the answers wrong, and makes a mockery of this whole page.  Please remember that Stack Overflow is intended to be a repository of questions and answers, for the benefit of future visitors.  It's a bit ridiculous if you make the question fail to match the answers.  If you have a brand new question, then please ask a brand new question.  But otherwise, please undo your edit.

Comment: @DavidWallace. Duly noted! I am sorry! I am noob on stack overflow. Thanks for the comment. I have changed my code back to the original. Sorry for the miscue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace sum(a) with System.out.println(sum(a)); and you should get true or false printed in console.

Comment: Bulatovid.  Oh interesting. Is this because sum(a) simply makes the object/method, but until I do System.out.println(sum(a)) the method will not be run? I am just starting java on my own and my previous language is python. This is the closest concept to what I have learned so far.

Comment: When you do System.out.println it will print result of sum(a). In this case it is true or false. If you return something else like number or string then it would print that.

Comment: @NenadBulatovic David Wallace. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to break for this sort of thing. Just replace your breaks with

```
return true;
```

When you `return` in Java, the code stops executing - it won't continue to run the result of your algorithm.

Just to give you an example, look at a method like this:

```
public boolean numberCheck(int number) {
    if(number == 20) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

If the number is equal to 20, the method will `return true` and then **stop** - it won't go on to `return false`, because once the return is called, the execution effectively stops.

Answer (score 2):

For your problem, you don't even need a `check` variable. Just call `return true;` when required... and `return false;` after your while loop